# Hiding input doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="AvatarfileSelected" value="image" 
       id="AvatarfileSelected" onclick="$('#extra').hide('slow')"/>
<span style="color:#538f05;">Change Image</span>
<div id="extra">
    <input type="file" name="avatarfile" id="avatarfile"></input>
</div>
```

The above code doesn't work. Could someone show me the mistakes?

Comment: If that's the case you would see an error in the JavaScript console

Comment: @Blaine Nope; semi-colons in javascript are not required for the code to work.

Comment: `input` tags are self-closing in XHTML, btw (referring to `#avatarfile`)

Comment: @Blaine. Not required in js. Just teasing you... :)

Comment: @gdoron I'm genuinely confused now about the role of the semicolon in JavaScript in-line one-liners lol

Comment: @Blaine. As long as you write only one "command" in a line, you don't need to use `;` as it's injected

Comment: @gdoron thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 3):

You probably didn't include jQuery...

Use vanilla javascript:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('extra').style.display = 'none'";
```

Instead of:

```
onclick="$('#extra').hide('slow')"
```

(Or include jQuery if you want to use it.)

---

BTW, `<input>` doesn't have a closing tag: `</input>`

Replace:

```
<input type="file" name="avatarfile" id="avatarfile"></input>
```

With:

```
<input type="file" name="avatarfile" id="avatarfile" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `onclick` event from the HTML markup and do it in [`unobutrusive`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) way. Make sure you bind your event functionalities in document [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.

Use it like this

```
$(function(){       
    $("#AvatarfileSelected").click(function(){    
       $("#extra").hide();        
    }); 
});​
```

Jsfiddle sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/p9tdf/1/

Comment: Though it's the right way to use jQuery, how does it answer the question...?